# Archive database on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, archive

I have a table with more than 60mio records, where every month I have to add about 2-4 milions. It's not insert only table, I need to read from it and update recently added rows (status changes, etc.). I have spotted some of my SELECT queries begun to ommit indexes because of number of rows to be searched using criterias.
   Therefore I want to archive records older than 6 months. Is there any good way to do this? Only thing I got in mind is manual copying data to archive db and remove at master. Perhaps there are some good practices or mechanisms to do it?

Michal

Answer (score 3):

I recently answered similar question here: [database-archive-solutions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28655/database-archive-solutions)

You should read about  [postgresql table partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28655/database-archive-solutions), if you have good way to split data in parts.